React-native: TouchableOpacity and Icon with absolute touchable background issue
I'm using TouchableOpacity for a card and there is a heart icon with white absolute background and for background I'm also using touchable opacity (for Icon BG). The problem I'm facing here is that whenever I click on Icon the card get clicked even though the icon is absolute.
I want to click the absolute Icon with BG and the card separately as wanted to navigate when clicked on card and when icon is clicked i wanted to change the icon on isLiked condition.
yes there is a solution that I should use View instead of TouchableOpacity for Icon BG and should use Icon onPress. But the thing is I need the Icon BG touchable for some reasons.

In the  tag, Apply zIndex: 9 in style props.
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {...}} style={{ zIndex: 9 }} />

